# Angular: conditional class with *ngClass

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-template, angular-ng-class

What is wrong with my Angular code? I am getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined at BrowserDomAdapter.removeClass

```html
<ol>
  <li *ngClass="{active: step==='step1'}" (click)="step='step1'">Step1</li>
  <li *ngClass="{active: step==='step2'}" (click)="step='step2'">Step2</li>
  <li *ngClass="{active: step==='step3'}" (click)="step='step3'">Step3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: What causes this error? I am also facing this.

Answer (score 2712, accepted):

Angular version 2+ provides several ways to add classes conditionally:

**type one**

```
    [class.my_class] = "step === 'step1'"
```

**type two**

```
    [ngClass]="{'my_class': step === 'step1'}"
```

and multiple option:

```
    [ngClass]="{'my_class': step === 'step1', 'my_class2' : step === 'step2' }"
```

**type three**

```
    [ngClass]="{1 : 'my_class1', 2 : 'my_class2', 3 : 'my_class4'}[step]"
```

**type four**

```
    [ngClass]="step == 'step1' ? 'my_class1' : 'my_class2'"
```

You can find these examples on the [documentation page](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description)

Comment: Perfect answer, just fix the type 2 to:
[ngClass]="{'my-class': step=='step1'}" 
With the '' int the class name

Comment: I was looking for the type four, but I'm wondering if I can add another class with another condition into that expression? Thanks in advance

Comment: For type three, the order of the class name and check is wrong. It should be class name first such as [ngClass]="{ 'my-class1': 1, 'my-class2': 2 }"

Comment: looks like "type three" and "type four" are specific usages of `[ngClass]="js expression returning html class string"` so that are the same in this sense

Comment: Looks like type four allows multiple classes also `[ngClass]="(step=='step1') ? 'my-class1 my-second-class1' : 'my-class2'"`

Comment: For type 4, in angular 10 i found that only the true case is applied, when false class attribute remain untouched (so in the example, my-class2 is not appended to original class attribute).

Comment: Can anyone link me to the documentation for type one? I can't find it on angular website

Comment: @MostafaMashayekhi can we apply multiple classes for the same condition? Is there a syntax for that?

Comment: featlorin - late but had the same question - https://angular.io/guide/class-binding

Answer (score 513):

`[ngClass]=...` instead of `*ngClass`.

`*` is only for the shorthand syntax for structural directives where you can for example use

```ts
<div *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</div>
```

instead of the longer equivalent version

```ts
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items">
  <div>{{item}}</div>
</template>
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

> ```ts
> <some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>
> <some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>
> <some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
> <some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>
> <some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
> ```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

> ```ts
> <!-- toggle the "special" class on/off with a property -->
> <div [class.special]="isSpecial">The class binding is special</div>
>
> <!-- binding to `class.special` trumps the class attribute -->
> <div class="special"
>      [class.special]="!isSpecial">This one is not so special</div>
> ```

> ```ts
> <!-- reset/override all class names with a binding  -->
> <div class="bad curly special"
>      [class]="badCurly">Bad curly</div>
> ```

Comment: From the angular documentation: "The asterisk is "syntactic sugar" for something a bit more complicated. Internally, Angular translates the *ngIf attribute into a <ng-template> element, wrapped around the host element, like this. The *ngIf directive moved to the <ng-template> element where it became a property binding,[ngIf].
The rest of the <div>, including its class attribute, moved inside the <ng-template> element." - more info @ https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-asterisk--prefix

Comment: Actually, it's nothing more complicated, `*` just allows a simplified synax instead of cannonical form.

Answer (score 101):

Another solution would be using `[class.active]`.

Example :

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li [class.active]="step=='step1'" (click)="step='step1'">Step1</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 96):

That's the normal structure for `ngClass` is:

```
[ngClass]="{'classname' : condition}"
```

So in your case, just use it like this...

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li [ngClass]="{'active': step==='step1'}" (click)="step='step1'">Step1</li>
  <li [ngClass]="{'active': step==='step2'}" (click)="step='step2'">Step2</li>
  <li [ngClass]="{'active': step==='step3'}" (click)="step='step3'">Step3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 83):

with the following examples you can use 'IF ELSE'

```
<p class="{{condition ? 'checkedClass' : 'uncheckedClass'}}">
<p [ngClass]="condition ? 'checkedClass' : 'uncheckedClass'">
<p [ngClass]="[condition ? 'checkedClass' : 'uncheckedClass']">
```

Comment: I tried the first and the second solution. Only the second worked for me

Answer (score 54):

You can use ngClass to apply the class name both conditionally and not in Angular

For Example

```
[ngClass]="'someClass'">
```

**Conditional**

```
[ngClass]="{'someClass': property1.isValid}">
```

**Multiple Condition**

```
 [ngClass]="{'someClass': property1.isValid && property2.isValid}">
```

**Method expression**

```
[ngClass]="getSomeClass()"
```

**This method will inside of your component**

```
 getSomeClass(){
        const isValid=this.property1 && this.property2;
        return {someClass1:isValid , someClass2:isValid};
    }
```

Comment: Hello, sorry, I'm a bit new to angular. Is using [ngClass]="getSomeClass()" considered a good practice? From what I can see in logs - it gets evaluated every few milliseconds. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jack It's depends , if you want to perform some additional business logic to apply the class , method will make more sense. Writing those logic on the html is tedious.

Answer (score 50):

Angular  provides multiple ways to add classes conditionally:

**First way**

active is your class name

```
[class.active]="step === 'step1'"
```

**Second way**

active is your class name

```
[ngClass]="{'active': step=='step1'}"
```

**Third way**

by using ternary operator class1 and class2 is your class name

```
[ngClass]="(step=='step1')?'class1':'class2'"
```

Comment: What is new compared to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 21):

You should use something (`[ngClass]` instead of `*ngClass`) like that:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li [ngClass]="{active: step==='step1'}" (click)="step='step1; '">Step1</li>
  (...)
```

Answer (score 19):

In `Angular 7.X`

The CSS classes are updated as follows, depending on the type of the expression evaluation:

- string - the CSS classes listed in the string (space delimited) are added
- Array - the CSS classes declared as Array elements are added
- Object - keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are removed.

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

Answer (score 16):

Additionally, you can add with method function:

**In HTML**

```
<div [ngClass]="setClasses()">...</div>
```

**In component.ts**

```
// Set Dynamic Classes
  setClasses() {
    let classes = {
      constantClass: true,
      'conditional-class': this.item.id === 1
    }

    return classes;
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

to extend MostafaMashayekhi his answer for option two>
you can also chain multiple options with a ','

```
[ngClass]="{'my-class': step=='step1', 'my-class2':step=='step2' }"
```

Also *ngIf can be used in some of these situations usually combined with a *ngFor

```
class="mats p" *ngIf="mat=='painted'"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [ngClass] or [class.classname], both will work the same.
`[class.my-class]="step==='step1'"`
   OR

`[ngClass]="{'my-class': step=='step1'}"`

Both will work the same!

Answer (score 8):

While I was creating a reactive form, I had to assign 2 types of class on the button. This is how I did it:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" [ngClass]="(formGroup.valid)?'btn-info':''" 
[disabled]="!formGroup.valid">Sign in</button>
```

When the form is valid, button has btn and btn-class (from bootstrap), otherwise just btn class.

Answer (score 7):

We can make class dynamic by using following syntax. In Angular 2 plus, you can do this in various ways:

```
[ngClass]="{'active': arrayData.length && arrayData[0]?.booleanProperty}"
```

```
[ngClass]="{'active': step}"
```

```
[ngClass]="step== 'step1'?'active':''"
```

```
[ngClass]="step? 'active' : ''"
```

Answer (score 6):

Let, YourCondition is your condition or a boolean property, then do like this

```
[class.yourClass]="YourCondition"
```

Answer (score 5):

The directive operates in three different ways, depending on which of three types the expression evaluates to:

1. If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or more space-delimited class names.
2. If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a class name.
3. If the expression evaluates to an array, each element of the array should either be a string as in type 1 or an object as in type 2. This means that you can mix strings and objects together in an array to give you more control over what CSS classes appear. See the code below for an example of this.

```
    [class.class_one] = "step === 'step1'"

    [ngClass]="{'class_one': step === 'step1'}"
```

For multiple options:

```
    [ngClass]="{'class_one': step === 'step1', 'class_two' : step === 'step2' }" 

    [ngClass]="{1 : 'class_one', 2 : 'class_two', 3 : 'class_three'}[step]"

    [ngClass]="step == 'step1' ? 'class_one' : 'class_two'"
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

```
[ngClass]="{'active': dashboardComponent.selected_menu == 'profile'}"
```

Answer (score 4):

`ngClass` syntax:

```
[ngClass]="{'classname' : conditionFlag}"
```

You can use like this:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li [ngClass]="{'active': step==='step1'}" (click)="step='step1'">Step1</li>
  <li [ngClass]="{'active': step==='step2'}" (click)="step='step2'">Step2</li>
  <li [ngClass]="{'active': step==='step3'}" (click)="step='step3'">Step3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3):

For `elseif` statement (less comparison) use like that: (For example you compare three statement)

```
<div [ngClass]="step === 'step1' ? 'class1' : (step === 'step2' ? 'class2' : 'class3')"> {{step}} </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not relevant with `[ngClass]` directive but I was also getting the same error as

> Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined at...

and I thought to be the error in my `[ngClass]` condition but it turned out the property I was trying to access in the condition of `[ngClass]` was not initialized.

Like I had this in my typescript file

```
element: {type: string};
```

and In my `[ngClass]` I was using

```
[ngClass]="{'active', element.type === 'active'}"
```

and I was getting the error

> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined at...

and the solution was to fix my property to

```
element: {type: string} = {type: 'active'};
```

Hope it helps somebody who is trying to match a condition of a property in `[ngClass]`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="collapse in " [ngClass]="(active_tab=='assignservice' || active_tab=='manage')?'show':''" id="collapseExampleOrganization" aria-expanded="true" style="">
 <ul>   <li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="{'active': active_tab=='manage'}">
<a routerLink="/main/organization/manage" (click)="activemenu('manage')"> <i class="la la-building-o"></i>
<p>Manage</p></a></li> 
<li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="{'active': active_tab=='assignservice'}"><a routerLink="/main/organization/assignservice" (click)="activemenu('assignservice')"><i class="la la-user"></i><p>Add organization</p></a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Code is good example of ngClass if else condition.

```
[ngClass]="(active_tab=='assignservice' || active_tab=='manage')?'show':''"

[ngClass]="{'active': active_tab=='assignservice'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this..

Define your class with ''

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li *ngClass="{'active': step==='step1'}" (click)="step='step1; '">Step1</li>
    <li *ngClass="{'active': step==='step2'}"  (click)="step='step2'">Step2</li>
    <li *ngClass="{'active': step==='step3'}" (click)="step='step3'">Step3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

The example is a bit big, but triggering a class instead of typing inline is my first preferred approach.
this way you can add as many possibilities as you want to your element.
There may be a way for those who want to bind more than one [ngClass] to a single element.

```html
<span class="inline-flex items-center font-medium" [ngClass]="addClass">{{ badge.text }}</span>
```

```js
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

type Badge = {
    size?: 'basic' | 'large';
    shape?: 'basic' | 'rounded';
    color?: 'gray' | 'red' | 'yellow' | 'green' | 'blue' | 'indigo' | 'purple' | 'pink';
    dot?: boolean;
    removeButton?: false;
    text?: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'bio-badge',
    templateUrl: './badge.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./badge.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class BioBadgeComponent {
    @Input() badge!: Badge;
    get addClass() {
        return {
            'px-2.5 py-0.5 text-sx': this.badge.size === 'basic',
            'px-3 py-0.5 text-sm': this.badge.size === 'large',
            'rounded-full': this.badge.shape === 'basic',
            'rounded': this.badge.shape === 'rounded',
            'bg-gray-100 text-gray-800': this.badge.color === 'gray',
            'bg-red-100 text-red-800': this.badge.color === 'red',
            'bg-yellow-100 text-yellow-800': this.badge.color === 'yellow',
            'bg-green-100 text-green-800': this.badge.color === 'green',
            'bg-blue-100 text-blue-800': this.badge.color === 'blue',
            'bg-indigo-100 text-indigo-800': this.badge.color === 'indigo',
            'bg-purple-100 text-purple-800': this.badge.color === 'purple',
            'bg-pink-100 text-pink-800': this.badge.color === 'pink',
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If user want to display the class on basis of && and ||
then below one is work for me

```
[ngClass]="{'clasname_1':  condition_1 && condition_2, 'classname_2':  condition_1 && condition2, 'classname_3': condition}"
```

Example:

```
[ngClass]="{'approval-panel-mat-drawer-side-left':  similar_toil_mode==='side' && showsTheSimilarToilsWithCloseIcon, 'approval-panel-mat-drawer-side-right':  similar_toil_mode==='side' && !showsTheSimilarToilsWithCloseIcon, 'approval-panel-mat-drawer-over': similar_toil_mode==='over'}"
```