# Assign classes conditionally in Angular2

Tags: angular, ng-class

I'm trying to conditionally assign a class to a div based on the value I obtained from my back-end system.

Say there is an object `'A'` which has a variable `status` which possibly has values `status1` and `status2`.

I'm trying to assign 2 classes (`class1` and `class2`) conditionally depending on the status using Angular 2. Following is the condition I'm using. Please suggest a working alternative for this,

```
<div ng-class="{status1 : 'class1', status2 : 'class2'}[A.status]">
   ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can bind your object to the `[ngClass]` directive

```
<div [ngClass]="{'active': isActive, 'disabled': isDisabled}">
```

almost the same syntax as angular 1. just add the square brackets

Comment: That worked! Thanks @eltonkamami.

As a follow-up question, is there some place I can read about specific syntaxes like these for Angular 2?

Comment: @RamanaSarva https://angular.io/cheatsheet this is the official angular 2 cheatsheet covering a lot of ng2 syntax

Comment: Class names in this case should be inside single brackets. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2 provide some way to add class with the condition , this link is helpful

[Angular 2 conditional class with *ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-2-conditional-class-with-ngclass/41974490#41974490)