# Angular 2 way of adding conditional classes to HTML tags

Tags: angular

I have this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="addSupplier(item)">Save</button>
```

I would like to add a class 'disabled' that will only applied when a certain condition is true, and will not apply when it is false.

What is the Angular 2 way of doing this?
I came up with this approach using *ngIf but it's a ton of code:

```
<div *ngIf="item.productId && item.supplier">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="addSupplier(item)">Save</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!item.productId || !item.supplier">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled" (click)="addSupplier(item)">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign classes conditionally in Angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195742/assign-classes-conditionally-in-angular2)

Comment: The answer provided here is different than the one at the link and I like it better. But the question is a duplicate.

Comment: I agree that is correctly marked as duplicate. But why are the answers irrelevant if they are different or better?

Comment: Again, there is no argument that this question is a duplicate and has been properly marked as such. But will users be able to continue to answer this question? As we have seen the answer that @Robin has provided here is better than the answer in the duplicate. This would actually suggest that asking a duplicate question can be a good thing for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" [class.disabled]="!item.productId || !item.supplier" (click)="addSupplier(item)">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The good old ngClass is still available in Angular 2. You can give a try if you want.

```
[ngClass]="{'my-class': isClassVisible }"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to disable the button you may not need a css class, bind to `[disabled]` like `[disabled]="disableButton"`