# Angular2 applying css classes with conditions

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to apply a class with col-md-9 if displaysidebar is true else class should be col-md-12

This is what i have tried but fails to work

```
<div class=" displaysidebar ? col-md-9 : col-md-12 ">
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#how-to-use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign classes conditionally in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195742/assign-classes-conditionally-in-angular2)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) along with [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding).

```
<div [ngClass]="displaysidebar ? 'col-md-9' : 'col-md-12'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Can do in either way:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'col-md-9': displaysidebar, 'col-md-12': !displaysidebar} ">
```

or

```
<div [ngClass]="displaysidebar? 'col-md-9': 'col-md-12';">
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

**Template**

```
 <div [ngClass]="(displaysidebar) ? 'col-md-9': 'col-md-12' ">
```

**Component**

```
   export class App {
      displaysidebar : boolean;
      constructor() {
        this.displaysidebar = true;
       }   

    }
```

Comment: dv is appreciated @jota haha, great way to support community now i guess

Comment: Rahul you are assigning string value to a boolean variable.

Comment: @Faisal thanks mate a typo my bad , had a spat with some one here thanks mate , i was editing it might have missed it . first it was like `sidebar ===" true" `. i changed to boolean missed that.