# Is it possible to use operators with ngClass?

Tags: angular

How can I use operators with ngClass ?
For example, I would like to apply a class only if `someValue` equals `otherValue`

```
[ngClass]="{active: someValue === otherValue}"
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35269611/3455035)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible according to [official reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any operators if in the end the expression will return true or false.

```
[ngClass]="{online: serverStatus === 'online'}"
```

This is my example - the expression returns true when serverStatus is online, and then class .online is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try the below code. The class `active` will get triggered when the condition someValue = otherValue.

```
[ngClass]="{'active': someValue == othervalue}"
```

or

```
[ngClass]="{'active': someValue === othervalue}"
```

If you want to add a class by checking with any specific value such as 0, pls try

```
[ngClass]="{'active': someValue == '0' }"
```