# Angular: use a class with *ngIf

Tags: angular

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li *ngFor="let t of todos; let i = index" class="list-group-item" >{{ t }}</li>
</ul>
```

`t` is a string. I want to have this element if `i == 0`:

```
<li class="list-group-item active" >{{ t }}</li>
```

and this element if `i > 0`:

```
<li class="list-group-item" >{{ t }}</li>
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974490)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use `[class.####]` notation for this sort of thing.

```
 <li *ngFor="let t of todos; let i = index" 
     class="list-group-item"
     [class.active]="i === 0">{{ t }}</li>
```

You can also use first.

```
 <li *ngFor="let t of todos; let i = first" 
     class="list-group-item"
     [class.active]="i">{{ t }}</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
<li *ngFor="let t of todos; let i = index" class="list-group-item" [class.active]="i==0" >{{ t }}</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let t of todos; let i = index" class="list-group-item" >
        <span [class.active]="i==0"> {{ t }} </span>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the same? In your case, the li does not have the class "active". Could be a problem if a css code is written for li.active or sth...