# Setting class for all Angular templates renderable with *ngIf

Tags: html, css, angular, templates

I have a class *section* on a DIV to be rendered. It works as expected.

```
<div *ngIf="decoded; then coordinates"></div>
<ng-template #coordinates>
  <div class="section">...</div>
</ng-template>
```

I tried moving the class assignment to the DIV containing the directive. The rendition did not work, though.

```
<div *ngIf="decoded; then coordinates" class="section"></div>
<ng-template #coordinates>
  <div>...</div>
</ng-template>
```

The outer DIV vanishes as a whole, being replaced by the contents of the template. It bugs me because I'm forced to add an extra DIV around everything in my template if I have several components in it. (Also, it seems kind of weird to me that we don't retain any properties of the tag used with `*ngIf` and can use any arbitrary one, while [it seems to work for `*ngFor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45740938/1525840).)

```
<div *ngIf="decoded; then coordinates"></div>
<ng-template #coordinates>
  <div class="section">
    <div>...</div>
    <span>...</span>
    <bzz>...</bzz>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

I tried cheating the browser by setting the class on template but since it's not actually rendered in the DOM as such, it failed, of course.

```
<div *ngIf="decoded; then coordinates"></div>
<ng-template #coordinates class="section">
  <div...</div>
</ng-template>
```

is there a way to force the DIV with the conditional directive to retain its class when being rendered according to the template's contents?

Comment: That happens because you explicitly used `then` to render something _other than_ the element `*ngIf` was on; if you'd just written `<div *ngIf="decoded" class="section">...</div>` it would have worked as you expected. Look at the examples of how structural directives are expanded in e.g. https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `ng-container` and apply `*ngIf` to it, in this case it should work as you expected

```
<div class="section">
  <ng-container *ngIf="decoded; then coordinates"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #coordinates>
  <div>...</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: it still bugs me a bit that in case with `ngFor`, the element with the directive is being rendered (repeatedly) including the its class, while `ngIf` "kills" it. That said, great answer. Quick too!

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR**: Angular is doing what you asked it to; you used `then` to tell it to render something *other than* the element the directive was on in the truth-y case. If that's not the behaviour you want, don't do that.

---

Structural directives like `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` are really a shorthand that gets expanded (this used to be referred to as *"desugaring"*), look at the examples in https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives or more specifically https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description:

> Simple form with shorthand syntax:
>
> ```
> <div *ngIf="condition">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
> ```
>
> Simple form with expanded syntax:
>
> ```
> <ng-template [ngIf]="condition">
>     <div>Content to render when condition is true.</div>
> </ng-template>
> ```

Note that everything gets wrapped up in `ng-template`s for conditional rendering.

---

If you had written your template like this:

```
<div *ngIf="decoded" class="section">...</div>
```

it would get expanded to:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="decoded">
  <div class="section">...</div>
</ng-template>
```

and what would actually be rendered is:

```
<div class="section">...</div>
```

Note that the class is still included, consistent with what you've experienced in other structural directives.

---

However, when you use `then`, the shorthand:

```
<div *ngIf="decoded; then coordinates" class="section"></div>
<ng-template #coordinates>
  <div>...</div>
</ng-template>
```

is expanded to:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="decoded" [ngIfThen]="coordinates">
  <div class="section"></div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #coordinates>
  <div>...</div>
</ng-template>
```

The content of the first `ng-template` is now irrelevant, because that's not what's rendered in either case. It's either going to render the `#coordinates` template content or nothing, so you get:

```
<div>...</div>
```

and your class seems to have disappeared. But that's what you asked for; the point of `then` is to **not** render the element the `*ngIf` was on, in the truth-y case, but to render something else instead.

---

For more on these underlying `ng-` elements, I wrote [Angular's "ng-" elements](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/May/20/angular-ng-elements.html) on my blog.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to take a look on this great article [Everything you need to know about ng-template, ng-content, ng-container, and *ngTemplateOutlet in Angula](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ng-template-ng-content-ng-container-and-ngtemplateoutlet-4b7b51223691/)

It contains all you need to know about Angular's structural directives with a good explanation and examples.