# Angular ngClass not working

Tags: html, angular, ng-class

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to get ngClass to work but it doesn't want to.
Here is my code:

```
<div *ngFor= "let job of dashboardJobsDetails" class="card">
    <div  ngClass="{'red card':job.status == 'Failed', 'yellow card': 
          job.status =='Warning', 'green card': job.status =='Success'}">
        Status: {{job.status}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The ngFor works great, the second div shows the correct status, but the ngClass never applies the style. Any ideas or tips?

Comment: Why did you think `ng-Class` *would* work? I'd recommend reading [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngClass) when you use things.

Comment: I tried the docs, I also tried every possible combination of ngClass (ngClass, ng-class, [ngClass], [ng-Class]) none of them worked. Just to answer your question, search ng-class in this site and you will find plenty of proof that it works.

Comment: `ng-class` was AngularJS (1.x). You could have shown an example that actually made sense in Angular (2+), rather than something that never would work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 conditional class with \*ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-2-conditional-class-with-ngclass)

Comment: A dup in my opinion, and the linked answer has some good resources

Comment: Given that you only have one of the three set, by the way, the best thing might be to write a property to provide that class name and just do e.g. `[class]="cardStatus"`

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is wrong, it should be

```
<div  [ngClass]="{'red card':job.status == 'Failed', 'yellow card': 
      job.status =='Warning', 'green card': job.status =='Success'}">
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean *exactly*? Do you have more than one `NgModule` in your application? If yes, did you import `CommonModule` in the additional NgModule?