# Angular 2 ngClass conditional with data?

Tags: css, angular, conditional-statements, ng-class

So I am basically trying to set a highlight if an object is selected already.  How can I compare the objects to change classes? Something like this

```
<[ngClass]="{{perkResult.perk === perk.perk}} ? 'highlight' : 'none-hightlight' ">
```

Current code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-12 benefit-selection">
     <ul class="benefits-dropdown-ul" *ngIf="perkList"> .     
      <a class="benefits-dropdown-div" *ngFor="let perkResult of perkList.results" (click)="onAddPerk(perkResult)">
       //highlight here
        <li class="benefits-dropdown-li">{{ perkResult.perk }}</li>
      </a>
     </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-6 benefit-selected" *ngFor="let perk of company.perks; trackBy: customTrackBy; let i = inde
    {{ perk.perk }}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do not need the interpolation brackets `{{}}`. In this case, `[ngClass]` is looking for an expression, so

```
[ngClass]="perkResult.perk === perk.perk ? 'highlight' : 'none-hightlight'"
```

or

```
[ngClass]="[perkResult.perk === perk.perk ? 'highlight' : 'none-hightlight']"
```

will work.

Comment: Great that works. But I have 2 for loops and perk.perk will not register in the location I want to place it. How can I reference it?

Comment: @Kenzo so `perk` and `perkResult` are in different scopes. I would suggest storing `perk.perk` in another variable. (say when something is selected). Then you can compare `perkResult.perk === newVar`

Answer (score -2):

You want the whole expression inside `{{}}` to evaluate to the class string you want

```
[ngClass]="{{perkResult.perk === perk.perk ? 'highlight' : 'none-hightlight'}}"
```

Comment: This solution will produce a compile error, because you can't use both [] square bracket operator and {{}} interpolation operator. A valid solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass/35269213#35269213