# Add a class by checking a condition in angular 6

Tags: angular6

I need to add a class `'test1'` if the values in `'emp_code'` and `'emp'` is same.

I had tried with the code,

```
class="{{ emp_empcode == emp ? 'test1' : 'test2' }}"
```

I had tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053809/angular-2-ngclass-conditional-with-data)

Any other way? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[class.test1]="emp_code == emp"
```

should definitively work. You can also take a look at https://toddmotto.com/ng-class-angular-classes for more varieties

Comment: Glad, that i could help :)