# Angular 4 how to apply dynamic styles?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to apply dynamic top and left values for ngFor repeated span element in Angular 4?

Comment: Yes, what do you want to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass

Comment: `<span [style.top]="topvalue"></span>` where `topvalue` is a variable.

Comment: [ngClass]="{'alert-card': hasError }"

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use:

1. the `[style.anything]` binding, to do something simple eg. `<span [style.color]="red"></span>`, or something more complicated like eg. bind a variable (here `progress`) to a percentage (`width`): `[style.width.%]="progress"`;
2. the `[ngStyle]` binding, allowing to specify several CSS **properties** at once, eg:  `<span [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red', 'font-weight': condition? 'bold':'300'}"></span>`
3. the `[className]` binding to apply a CSS class name dynamically, eg: `<span [className]="condition? 'redText': 'blueText'"></span>`
4. the `[ngClass]` binding that allows specifying multiple CSS ***classes*** at once, just like `ngStyle`does for CSS **properties**, eg:
   `<span [ngClass]="{'redText': condition1, 'blueText': condition2}"></span>`

`[ngClass]` receives an object as its input, and applies each one of that object's keys *only if* the respective value evaluates to true.

For instance, if you're iterating over the array `items_array`:

```
<span *ngFor="let i of items_array" 
    [ngClass]="{'redText': i.shouldBeRed, 'blueText': i.shouldBeBlue}">
  The span text
</span>
```

the CSS class of each element (`i`) will be:

- `redText` if the attribute `i.shouldBeRed` evaluates to true (that is: it's `true`, `1`, a non-empty string, or a non-null object;
- `blueText` if the attribute i.shouldBeBlue evaluates to true;
- `redText blueText` if both attributes evaluate to true.

In your case, I guess that `[ngStyle]` would be appropriate:

```
<span *ngFor="let i of items_array" 
      [ngStyle]="{'top': expression1, 'left': expression2}">
    The span content
</span>
```