# how to apply condition on class in a div element

Tags: angular, typescript

How to apply CSS class condition to the below div element

i tried the below code but it is not working

```
  <div Class="{toolsMenuWidthSet==true?'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-custom-width-links':'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-custom-width-links-2'}"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="appsDropdownPopup">
```

I want if toolsMenuWidthSet is true then apply the "dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-custom-width-links" else apply  "dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-custom-width-links-2"

Comment: See this one [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48223518/11719787)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. There is a directive called `ngClass` in angular which you can use like this

```
 <div [ngClass]="toolsMenuWidthSet == true ? 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-custom-width-links' : 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-custom-width-links-2'"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="appsDropdownPopup">
```

but if you don't want to use `ngClass` directive so you can also go with angular binding like this

```
<div class="{{toolsMenuWidthSet == true ? 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-custom-width-links' : 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-custom-width-links-2'}}"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="appsDropdownPopup">
```

Comment: if we are using ngclass do we need to import something? As i tried this but it is not working for me

Comment: No, There was a typo in my answer. I updated my answer please see updated answer

Comment: This is working but my css style is not getting applied as expected
before all items were coming inside the div horizontal now it is coming vertical

Comment: if i put like class= 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-custom-width-links'  it comes horizontal

Comment: This is because the last CSS is not getting applied

Answer (score 0):

> Use [ngClass]

```
 <div [ngClass]="{'dropdown-menu':toolsMenuWidthSet, 'dropdown-menu-right dropdown-custom-width-links':toolsMenuWidthSet, 'dropdown-menu': !toolsMenuWidthSet, 'dropdown-menu-right dropdown-custom-width-links-2':!toolsMenuWidthSet}"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="appsDropdownPopup">
```

The CSS classes are updated as follows, depending on the type of the expression evaluation:

string - the CSS classes listed in the string (space delimited) are added,

Array - the CSS classes declared as Array elements are added,

Object - keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are removed.

Doco:https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: this does not work. Do i need to import something because with this none of the CSS are getting applied for this div element

Comment: Sorry, you need to separate each class.. will update answer.. no you do not need to import anything

Comment: Try to render toolsMenuWidthSet {{toolsMenuWidthSet}} to see its value as well.

Comment: {{toolsMenuWidthSet}} is fine

Comment: mmm. can you put your code on stackblitz to check it with you? not sure why it is not working then

Answer (score 0):

Use this one, it's working fine.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" 
    [ngClass]="toolsMenuWidthSet==true ?
    ' dropdown-custom-width-links' : 
    ' dropdown-custom-width-links-2'"
    aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" 
    id="appsDropdownPopup">
```