# How do I add a class to certain elements in an iterable using Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an iterable which is being used in an ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let item in items">{{item.name}}</div>
```

I also have a method getNumberOfSpecialItems() which returns the number of special items, say N.

I would like to apply a class "special" to the first N divs in the ngFor.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What part of that are you stuck on, exactly? What would *"best"* mean to you? [The docs](https://angular.io/docs) show you how to: get the index in `ngFor`; dynamically add or remove a class; call methods from the template; etc. Please give a [mcve] of your  implementation, outlining a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that it should be done like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item in items; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'special': i < getNumberOfSpecialItems()}">{{item.name}}</div>
```

where *i* - item's index in the list.

Probably, it would be better to assign *getNumberOfSpecialItems()* to a variable in the controller and to use this variable, because *NgClass* is a watcher and in the case above function will be invoked every iteration.

**Update:** There are several ways in Angular 5 to bind class parameter conditionally which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass).

Comment: One downside to this approach is the fact that the POJO passed to the `ngClass` directive will be created in every change detection cycle. Because of this, the `ngClass` receives a "new" input object (different object reference) meaning that the `<div>` node in the DOM will be repainted every time. TL;DR; perfomance is bad

Answer (score 0):

I normally prefer **property binding** over the `NgClass` directive when setting a class depends on a `boolean` evaluation:

```
<div *ngFor="let item in items; index as i"
      [class.special]="i < getNumberOfSpecialItems()">
{{item.name}}
</div>
```

In the template, `i` is the `index` value exposed by the `NgForOf` directive

Comment: Would be great if you format your code and put some more details about your solution.

Answer (score -1):

**I used this Approach:**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; index as count">
    <ngcontainer *ngIf="count<getNumberOfSpecialItems() else simple">
      <div ngClass="special"> {{item.name}} </div>
</ng-container>
   <ng-template #simple>
      <div> {{item.name}} </div>
   <ng-template>
</ng-container>`
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: isn't that a little bit overcomplicated?

Comment: why would you say that on gods green earth?? the solution uses if else clause how come it's overcomplicated.? @Jota. Toledo

Comment: If its not obvious to you, I guess its not worth explaining

Comment: I just gave an alternate solution.

Comment: Yeah its an alternative, but not a good one IMO. Whats the purpose of using ngClass over simply class in this case, if the class to be aplied is constant? What if instead of rendering a simple div, OP now wants to render a larger templare. Would he really want to write that 2 times, with only a small difference between the both? I dont think so