# Angular2 use *ngif to set class name in html code

Tags: angular, classname, angular-ng-if

I've tried some stuff cause I am building a weather dashboard.

I load weather data with http and subscribe, so I'll getting an observable back I cannot go trough like an array in typescript to add new properties.

For example I want to look on each weather data and look if a value has more than 70 °F and tell the weatherdata item to add a new property "weatherdata-sun-hot". Otherwise it should use an other class name "weatherdata-sun-normal" I would use this as a class name to put it in html later with interpolation.

So my idea is to solve this with the html template

So far I do have my code here

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of weatherdata">{{item.dt_txt}} | {{item.main.temp_min}} -> {{item.main.temp_max}}</li>
</ul>
```

Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you need conditional class, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass

Comment: @AliAdravi: Thanks for the hint but I cannot see the if/else mechanism there. Like if val greater than something than use classname x otherwhise classname y. Can you give me a quick example? :-)

Thanks again.

Comment: @AliAdravi: I've come up with a working solution I tried:

`<li *ngFor="let item of weatherdata" [ngClass]="[item.main.temp_max > 17 ? 'weather-sun-hot' : 'weather-sun-normal']" >{{item.dt_txt}} | {{item.main.temp_min}} -> {{item.main.temp_max}}</li>`

But for me it's looking like ugly code. Or would you implement it the same way? I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ngClass directive:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of weatherdata" [ngClass]="{'weatherdata-sun-hot': item.main.temp_min > 70, 'weatherdata-sun-normal': item.main.temp_min <= 70}">
        {{item.dt_txt}} | {{item.main.temp_min}} -> {{item.main.temp_max}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or you can do it in the component's code and bind to it:

**template**

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of weatherdata" [ngClass]="tempClass(item)">
        {{item.dt_txt}} | {{item.main.temp_min}} -> {{item.main.temp_max}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**component**

```
@Component(...)
class MyComponent {
    tempClass(item): any {
        const hot = item.main.temp_min > 70;
        return {
            'weatherdata-sun-hot': hot,
            'weatherdata-sun-normal': !hot
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the perspective... I should have thought of that :-) So easy and good. Have a nice day.