# Angular2 how to change a css calls using ng class but only for specific elements

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-accordion and when a user clicks mat-expansion-panel I want to change out the icon CSS class so far I have that working but I need it to change the class for only the selected panel here is my code

**html**

```html
<mat-expansion-panel hideToggle (opened)="onExpand()" (closed)="onCollapse()">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      <mat-icon [ngClass]="calculateClasses()" id="panel1">lock</mat-icon>
      <div>
        <div class="header-text">Change password</div>
        <div class="header-text-sub">*********</div>
      </div>
    </mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <app-change-password></app-change-password>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

**ts**

```js
onExpand() {
  this.panelOpenState = true
}

onCollapse() {
  this.panelOpenState = false
}

calculateClasses() {
  let element = document.getElementById('panel1');
  //document.getElementById('panel1')
  if (this.panelOpenState == true) {
    return "circle-icon-selected"
  } else {
    return "circle-icon"
  }
}
```

Trying to change the code for `mat-icon [ngClass]="calculateClasses()"`

Updated code, as you can see there are two panels and I only want to change the icon in the panel that is currently opened

```html
<mat-expansion-panel hideToggle (opened)="onExpand()" (closed)="onCollapse()">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      <mat-icon [ngClass]="panelOpenState ? 'circle-icon-selected' : 'circle-icon'">lock</mat-icon>
      <div>
        <div class="header-text">Change password</div>
        <div class="header-text-sub">*********</div>
      </div>
    </mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <app-change-password></app-change-password>
</mat-expansion-panel>

<mat-expansion-panel hideToggle (opened)="onExpand()" (closed)="onCollapse()">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      <mat-icon [ngClass]="panelOpenState ? 'circle-icon-selected' : 'circle-icon'">phone_outline</mat-icon>
      <div>
        <div class="header-text">Change support PIN</div>
        <div class="header-text-sub">3402</div>
      </div>
    </mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <app-support-pin></app-support-pin>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: you could use a conditional operator on ng class

Comment: Thanks how would that work?

Comment: like so `[ngClass]="isSet? 'class1': 'class2'"`

Answer (score 1):

Read this [one](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)  or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass).

[ngClass]="panelOpenState ? 'circle-icon-selected' : 'circle-icon'"

```
onExpand(num:number) {
    if(num==1) {
        this.panel1OpenState = true;
    } else if(num==2) {
        this.panel2OpenState = true;
    }
}

onCollapse(num:number) {
    if(num==1) {
        this.panel1OpenState = false;
    } else if(num==2) {
        this.panel2OpenState = false;
    }
}
```

And now call the function like onExpand(1) and onCollapse(1) in first panel and so on by changing number.

Comment: That changes it for all the panels I have 5 panels and only want to change it for the selected or opened one

Comment: @AlmogKoren Sorry, I am unable to understand the problem. Please share code and describe the problem in detail.

Comment: Updated the Answer. Please check and revert.

Comment: This works but it means you have to create panelOpenState1 for each panel I have 10 so it's a lot vars, I was looking for something like jquery select element by id

Comment: you can define array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176647/discussion-between-bhaskar-rajoriya-and-almog-koren).

Comment: panelOpenState = []; 

// define this.panelOpenState[i] = false; in loop 

onExpand(num:number) { 
this.panelOpenState[num] = true; 
} 

onCollapse(num:number) { 
this.panelOpenState[num] = false; 
}

Comment: No I did something else

Comment: Ok. Please post the Solution here.