# Send condition as variable to class name in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to give conditional class a div. But my problem is, I want "myClassCondition" as a string like below. When I write like this `<div [class]="7 > 6 ? 'bg-red' : null"> MyText </div>`, it is working perfectly. But I want send from `.ts` file as variable like below. How can I do this?

```
<div [class]="myClassCondition"> MyText </div>
```

-

```
myClassCondition = "7 > 6 ? 'bg-red' : null";
```

Comment: You can check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974490/7812112)

Comment: Thanks but there isn't what I was looking for in that link @SarthakAggarwal

Comment: you want to send _class_ name from .ts ?

Comment: No I want send condition not class name @SarthakAggarwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the quotes in your Ts part to

```
myClassCondition = 7 > 6 ? 'bg-red' : null;
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ce3zgm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @HasanOzdemir it works for me , unless there is an issue with your class itself (bg-red). check the updated answer i provided a stackblitz;

Comment: Thanks a lot @selemmn. But my IDE underline the code in .ts file like an error.

Comment: Visual studio 2017

Comment: Opened and closed My IDE. and it's fixed. Thanks again @selemmn

Comment: @HasanOzdemir Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following

**.component.html**

```
<div [class.bg-red]="myClassCondition"> MyText </div>
```

**.component.ts**

```
myClassCondition = 7 > 6 ? true : false;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SarthakAggarwal. This worked. But what I was looking for is selemmn's answer. But this information also very helpful for me. Because i don't know usage like `[class.bg-red]`. I learnt new thing.