# OnClick change the background color using Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular7

I have the ul tag when the user clicks on the list the background color has to change to some other color.I am using Angular7 and am new to this. how can i achieve this.

HTML:

```
<ul class="horizontal" id="nav">
  <li><a class="active">Draft</a></li>
  <li><a>Planned</a></li>
  <li><a>Started</a></li>
  <li><a>Suspended</a></li>
  <li><a>Ended</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul.horizontal li {
  float: left;
}

ul.horizontal {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.horizontal li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 16px 0 32px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.horizontal li a.active {
  background-color: #0275E7;
  color: #ffff;
  // background-color: rgb(201, 205, 248);
}
```

Comment: You can use `[ngClass]` to do this. More docs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi onclick i want to change the color

Comment: You should understand why, not copy-pasta the solution without understanding the reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<ul class="horizontal" id="nav">
  <li 
    *ngFor="let state of states"
    (click)="setStateAsActive(state)">
    <a [class.active]="state === activeState">
      {{ state }}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And in your TS Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  activeState = 'Draft';

  states = [
    'Draft',
    'Planned',
    'Started',
    'Suspended',
    'Ended',
  ]

  setStateAsActive(state) {
    this.activeState = state;
  }

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tab-active-toggle-on-tap-or-click?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.