# How to use if-else condition with [ngClass] in angular 7?

Tags: angular, ng-class

I want to use multiple classes inside Angular [ngClass].
I have two classes, It should work accordingly as per the condition of the flag, that are already passed from the component.ts.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You'll need to share some more information along with some code. Please have a look around and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 63):

Do like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="condition ? 'class1' : 'class2' " ></div>
```

(Ternary Operator Usage)

Answer (score 36):

You can do this in several ways :

number one :

```
[class.my-class]="step=='step1'"
```

number twe :

```
[ngClass]="{'my-class': step=='step1'}"
```

number three :

```
[ngClass]="{'my-class': step=='step1', 'my-class2':step=='step2' }"
```

number four :

```
[ngClass]="(step=='step1')?'my-class1':'my-class2'"
```

you can get help this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass?rq=1) for more help

Answer (score 6):

You can try `[ngClass]="condition ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'"` or `[ngClass]="[condition ? 'checked' : 'unchecked']"`

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this 
`[ngClass]="{'class1':condition1, 'class2':condition2}"`.

Comment: you can also add condition like `conditionMatch ?  true : false`.

Answer (score 2):

html :

```
  <div [ngClass]="{'class1' : value == 1, 'class2' : value == 2}">
      ....................... 
  </div>

   by using a function
  <div  [ngClass]="getClass(2)">
    .......................

  </div>
```

ts :

```
export class AppComponent  {
value = 1;

getClass(value){
  if(value == 1) return 'class1'
  else if(value == 2) return 'class2'
}
}
```