# In angular, how to add a class using the brackets?

Tags: css, angular, angular-template

Is it possible to create something like below?

```html
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <p class="quote {{post.color}}-quote">
    {{ post.content }}
    <span class="author">Anatoly Weinstein, Founder of Theora</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Important line: `class="quote {{post.color}}-quote"`

I've seen [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass) issues, but I don't want to use booleans and hardcode every element.

Comment: I am question banned. How can this question be improved? HELP ME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special reason to use the template binding with brackets, this can be done
with the `ngClass` directive:

```
<p class="quote" [ngClass]="[post.color+'-quote']">
```