# angular - body tag class name inside ngif condition

Tags: javascript, angular

Body tag can have two possible class name `dark` and `light`, what is the best way to check which class is active inside HTML without declaring variables in .ts file

```
<body class="dark"></body>
       or
<body class="light"></body>

<img *ngIf="If body is having class name 'dark' show this">
<img *ngIf="If body is having class name 'light' show this">
```

I tried this, But not working

```
<img *ngIf="document.body.className === 'dark'">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass This could help.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add a variable in your component and check that var in your img and body *ngIf?

```
<body [class]="myVar=="dark" ? 'dark' : 'light'">
<img *ngIf="myVar='dark'">
```

Comment: This is not feasible when you have many components, so searching for a solution with logic involves only inside HTML!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to set both the theme and the img

```
theme = 'dark' ;

<body ng-class="{theme === 'dark' ? 'dark' : 'light'}"></body>
<img *ngIf="theme == 'dark'"> 
<img *ngIf="theme !== 'dark'">
```

Comment: In this solution, we need to declare the theme variable in all components!! So I'm looking for a solution using only HTML, so that it will eliminate declaring theme variable in all the components!!

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible approach already mentioned in other answers, Since we need to solve this problem without using ts or js

We can solve it using css and HTML only

Approach here is despite of adding ngIf to load different image we can use css to load different image

```
<body class="dark">
<img class="image-replacement"  />


</body>

.dark .image-replacement {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://akamaicovers.oreilly.com/images/9780596517748/cat.gif) no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 236px;
  padding-left: 180px;
}

.light .image-replacement {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://ashlandtech.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/1.png) no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 236px;
  padding-left: 180px;
}
```

Please find Working fiddle linkhttps://jsfiddle.net/vickykumarui/4po9hu6g/

As far as your code is concerned it is correct 
There may be one reason why it is not working is because document is not injected in your angular component
Once you inject document in your angular component it will start working

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
}
```

Please find working demo of the approach you followed
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qighyt

Answer (score 0):

```
<body class="light" #classref>
    <img *ngIf="classref.className === 'dark'" title="dark">
    <img *ngIf="classref.className === 'light'" title="light">
</body>
```

> You can set reference variable for elements.Here I used 
>   classref as reference variable for body element, so we can check the class name by  *ngIf.

Comment: This will work only in root component since body tag will not present in the child components