# How to apply css class based on condition that char length > 128

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ng-class

This is angular app, I want to apply css class based on condition that char length of variable is greater than 128 char. I was inspired by this post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass). As shown below in the code snippets, I am trying to dynamically apply style based on condition that charlen value is within or outside 128.
Please I am new to Angular and I am npot aware of many concepts, thnak you for suggestions.

**template.html**

```
<input [ngClass] = "(charlen <128)?'class1':'class2' />
```

**template.ts**

```
str:String;
charlen:Number;

ngInit () {
 str="this is not 128 char";
 charlen = str.length;
}
```

**template.css**

```
.class1 {
color:red;
}

.class2 {
 color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```html
<input [ngClass]="{ 'class1': charlen < 128, 'class2': charlen >= 128 }" />
```

Comment: You forget the "{" and "}"

Answer (score 1):

Using class with property binding, we can achieve the above

.html

```
<input [class] = "(charlen <128)?'class1':'class2'" />
```

.ts

```
str:String;
charlen:Number;

ngOnInit() {
  this.str= "this is not 128 char";
  this.charlen = this.str.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';

  str:String;
charlen:Number;

ngOnInit () {
 this.str="this is not 128 char";
 this.charlen = this.str.length;
}
}
```

and use same html code, it is working.

check [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdgpnr)

Do let me know if you face any issue.