# Primeng's [styleClass] with conditional styling

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'd like to put a conditional styling on a primeng 'p-overlayPanel' element. I have tried:

1. `<p-overlayPanel [styleClass]="#{(bean.comment) ? 'style1' : 'style2'}">`, but it's not working.
2. `[ng-class]="bean.comment ? 'style1' : 'style2'"` - this is not working either.

Styleclass works only without a condition like so:

- `<p-overlayPanel [styleClass]="style1">` // html file
- `p-overlayPanel .style1.ui-overlay { background-color: yellow; }` // css file

While [ng-class] doesn't work at all (but works fine on vanilla JS elements). Have I missed something? My questions are following:

1. Is 'ng-class' not working for some of the elements from ngPrime collection?
2. How to correctly conditionally apply 'styleClass' for `p-overlayPanel` element?
   I'm using Angular 8.

Comment: There are several options listed in this answer, one of them should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass. In your case type 4 will apply to you: [ngClass]="(step=='step1')?'my-class1':'my-class2'"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: conditional class with \*ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass)

Comment: @ulmas this related to primeng and how you can change the style of these element the have something like add a styleclass then you can change the them same as my answer  

Answer (score 4):

**styleClass** accept string as a css class or list of classes and apply to the elemnt at that already have a list of these classes `overlaypanel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow`

so if you want to change the background color you have to do it like this

```css
.style1.ui-overlaypanel{
  background-color: red;
}

.style2.ui-overlaypanel{
  background-color: green;
}
```

> you have to add the class to the global style file not the component style file and if you use `style` property the value will pass to ngStyle directive.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rzid1c-wbtpzu)

[overlaypanel.ts](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/overlaypanel/overlaypanel.ts)

**Updated**

you can use `ngClass` but the style must be change like the example below , because now the css classes will apply to the element directly.

```css
.style1 .ui-overlaypanel{
  background-color: red;
}

.style2 .ui-overlaypanel{
  background-color: green;
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rzid1c-huezja)

Comment: Thanks, the updated answer works. For those who is new to PrimeNG :- it has to be adapted accordingly for each component. E.g. for sidebar, use .ui-sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ngClass] like this:

```
<input
  pInputText
  [ngModel]="vendor.iban"
  name="pIban"
  #pIban="ngModel"
  (click)="some(pIban)"
  class="col-md-7 ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
  [ngClass]="{
    'errorVendor': vendor.iban == '' && pIban.touched
  }"
/>
```