# How to remove an animation from a component when it is being used inside another Angular Component?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-animations

I have created an Angular Component which adds styling and some animation to a photo. I want to use the same photo styling in another component, but I don't want the animation to transfer over to the new component.

Animation on picture:

```
.pic
{
position: relative;
height: 13em;
width: 12em;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 2em auto 0em auto;

animation-name: pop;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-delay: 3.5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
opacity: 0;
}
```

When I create a new component and add the selector tag of this component into the new component, the image is displayed with this animation. Is there a way I can remove this animation in the new component that I created?

A lot of you are suggesting this:

```
.pic
{
    position: relative;
    height: 13em;
    width: 12em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 2em auto 0em auto;

.anime
{
    animation-name: pop;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}
}
```

When i add the selector tag of this component which is `<app-main-pic></app-main-pic>` into the other component, that anime class is still present on the .pic, therefore the image will still get animated

New Component:

```
   <div>
     <app-main-pic></app-main-pic>
   </div>

 <body>



</body>
```

Comment: Why not add another class to the non-animated pictures like ```class="pic non-animated"``` then add another style ```.pic .non-animated { animation: none; opacity: 1 }```

Comment: Theres only 1 picture and if I add a class called .animate, when I use it in my new component, that class will still be there because when we use a selector tag inside another component, it inherits all properties/classes of that component.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you an easier way to do this, just write an other CSS class without animation :

```
.pic-no-animation
{
position: relative;
height: 13em;
width: 12em;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 2em auto 0em auto;
}
```

or try to apply `[ngStyle]="{'animation-name': none}"` on your html tag

Comment: Should i create a boolean in typescript and then add that class if the boolean is true? Because if I create a seperate class for no animation, the class thats causing the animation will still be on the HTML element. Somehow we will need to remove that .animation class won't we?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a picture styling and a picture animation. So, let's reduce your `pic` class to be reusable

```
.pic
{
position: relative;
height: 13em;
width: 12em;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 2em auto 0em auto;
}
```

so far, so good. Now let's define a class, which, if present on your `pic`, it animates

```
.pic.animate
{
animation-name: pop;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-delay: 3.5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
opacity: 0;
}
```

so, if `pic` has `animate`, then it's animated. If not, then it's not animated.

Comment: But when i add the selector tag into my new component, the animate class will still be there...

Comment: @MysticalMamba the animate class should only be given if the tag is animated. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass

Answer (score 0):

So I realized that as long as the animation is on the class '.pic', my picture will have an animation. I solved this problem by creating a whole new component just for the styling of the image.

Therefore, if I want an animation on the image, I will import the selector tag into a new component and add a class called '.animation' on the selector tag and create the animation in the css.

If i dont want an animation, I only need to put the selector tag of the component as the image does not have an animation initially.