# Is it possible to change element styling based on object property in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, angular-directive

I have class with some properties:

```
export class Task {
    name: string;
    state: number;
}
```

In my component.ts I have an **array of objects** with class *Task* (tasks).

In template I show them like this:

```
<div *ngFor='let task of tasks'>
  <p>{{ task.name }}</p>
  <p>{{ task.state }}</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible to change styling of my div based on *task.state* property? For example, I want it to be with red background when it's 0 and yellow when it's 1. I think I need to use directives, but I can't understand how.

Comment: You can just use [ngClass]

Comment: @MikeOne And what should I write inside it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass

Comment: [ngClass] = “{‘redClass’: task.state === 0, ‘yellowClass’: task.state === 1}”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Angular gives you two directives to style your element. You can use
> either `ngStyle` or `ngClass` for styling purpose.

In your scenario you can use -

-**ngClass**

Firstly create two css classes with name 'red-bg' and 'ylow-bg' according to their behaviour.

```
<div *ngFor='let task of tasks' [ngClass]="task.state === 0?'red-bg':'ylow-bg'">
  <p>{{ task.name }}</p>
  <p>{{ task.state }}</p>
</div>
```

**-ngStyle**

```
<div *ngFor='let task of tasks' [ngStyle]="{'background-color':task.state===0?'red':'yellow'}">
   <p>{{ task.name }}</p>
   <p>{{ task.state }}</p>
</div>
```