# How to achieve the icon change scenario in angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and have a below code.

```
<span
    class="fas fa-star"
    [ngClass]="isFavorite"
    class="far fa-star"
    [ngClass]="!isFavorite"
    (click)="onClick()"
></span>
```

By using the font-awesome icon, when I click the star icon, the icon is changed. However, the code above didn't work when I click the star button. How to achieve my issue by changing the my code without large modification?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<span class="fa-star"
    [ngClass]="{'fas': isFavorite, 'far': !isFavorite}"
    (click)="onClick()"></span>
```

Comment: @sclee1: You can also use `[ngClass]="{isFavorite ? 'fas' : 'far'}"`. Have a look on conditional classes in angular [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974490/3623608).