# Angular : Color cannot be changed with ngClass using bootstrap class "text-white"

Tags: html, angular, colors, background-color, ng-class

Color cannot be changed with ngClass using bootstrap class "text-white".

Code:

```
[ngClass] = "{'text-white': log >= 5}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: conditional class with \*ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubbzkh?file=src/app/app.component.css) Your syntax is correct if log is a number. Firstly check if it is number then be sure that class has style attribute in css in application

in your component css add this to check

```
.text-white{
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: It is already working as you mentioned. But I mean the bootstrap class "text-white" ?