# Using Angular, can i set the CSS class within '*ngFor' depending on the values of each object I iterate through?

Tags: angular, ngfor

So I am trying to build a small web application with Angular and Firebase, where said application should display a list of players. This list of players I render like this:

```
<ul class="team">
    <li *ngFor="let player of players">
      <span class="icon icon-*xyz*"></span> {{ player.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**What I want**: Depending on the player id I want to style the span differently. Hence I would like the class "icon-xyz" to be icon-123, where 123 equals player.id.

**Why I want this:** I have a big picture with portraits of each player and with setting this class I exactly "cut" out the necessary portrait.

**What I tried / question:** I went through the Angular docs and Google in search of a functionality of Angular, which would help me here - without success. I found out that React provides a functionality, where components have a "probs" functionality which can access object properties to change styling. I have not found something similar for Angular and now my question is if there is some good solution for my problem or if I should change my approach totally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: conditional class with \*ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass)

Comment: I don't recommend you to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass, since in your case this will make your code grow with every player you add to the list.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Conditional classing is not applicable for my use case, as I have a couple of hundred players.

Comment: I meant using the `[class]="myVariable"` syntax used at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35269213/5015356)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, I think you could add the class name as a property of the player object, setting the needed class name in every player. Then you can use this

`<span class="icon {{player.icon}}"></span> {{ player.name }}`

Here's an example of how this works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-buv8dr

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an object to base properties off of, you have multiple options.

[Stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k48qgz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Example:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  <span ngClass="{{user.role}}">
    <img src="{{user.icon}}" height="50px" />
    <div >{{user.name}}</div>
  </span>   
</div>
```

You could use ngClass to add / remove classes. Any property or expression can work here as required.

You could also use property binding to append the DOM as the data dictates. For this example: we have a name, a role (color of the underline), and a picture (random hosted images on Google).

[image]

Comment: The provided solution by @Eliezer Veras Vargas does the trick for me, but your approach is also totally working. Just a follow-up question: What is the benefit of using 'ngClass' instead the normal css 'class'?

Comment: @velko93 FYI, you can upvote AND accept as answers are helpful. But to the follow up question: using class is just binding a value to the element. ngClass is an Angular directive which allows some cooler things, like an expression : [ngClass]="{'extra-sparkle': isDelightful}" or even conditional ternary operators. ngClass is much more flexible, so as  a better practice I'd generally use it to minimize changes later if the requirements change what possible classes would be required changes.