# Angular *ngIf toggle between 3 classes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a div in angular and I want to toggle between 3 classes.

So in the html I have:

```
<div *ngIf="status">Content Here</div>
```

In my .ts file I have a variable:

```
status = 'closed';
```

The status can have 3 values...

```
closed, opened or hidden.
```

Depending on the status value I need to add a different class or css to the div.

How can I do that?

Comment: See [Angular: conditional class with *ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **`ngClass`** to achive this.

```
 <div *ngIf="status" 
       [ngClass]="{'closedClass': status == 'closed', 
                   'openedClass': status == 'opened', 
                   'hiddenClass': status == 'hidden' }">Content Here</div>
```

**Hope this helps :)**

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, the easiest is:

```
<div [class.class1]="status == 'closed'" [class.class2]="status == 'opened'" [class.class3]="status == 'hidden'">Content Here</div>
```

You can also use ngClass:

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'class1':status == 'closed', 'class2':status == 'opened' ... }"></div>
```