# CSS use calc() for calculate height

Tags: css, angular, height

I would like to calculate the min-height of an element doing somening like that:

```
min-height: calc(50vh - height-of-other-element);
```

where height-of-other-element is height of a element that can be rendered or not using angular *ngIf.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

if you use a template reference and **not** `*ngIf="condition"` else `[style.display]="!condition?'none':null` you can use some like

```
<div #element [style.display]="!toogle?'none':null" >
...
</div>

<div [style.min-height]="'calc(50vh - '+element.getBoundingClientRect().height+'px)'" >
   ...
</div>
```

You can see an example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y9dzgf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

NOTE: I think that you can use css flex wrapping the two divs in another one and not use "calc". If you want to know about css flex, I like this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a conditional class via `ngIf`.
Basically you can create 2 css classes, one with `min-height: calc(50vh - height-of-other-element);` and other only with `min-height: 50vh`.
Then in your HTML, use something like `ngClass` to select the correct class for your div.

You can check this question to see some examples: [Angular: conditional class with *ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass)