# Angular how to conditionally change css class?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have an icon with a default class , the class name is card-icon , now how do I change the class based on condition or disable the class ?

Because the default color of the icon is gray now when condition is met or condition true I want to change it to black color.

The condition is below , when condition is true disable class="card-icon" or if it is not possible to disable then replace when a new class for example  [class.newclass] .

Any idea how to implement this guys ? Thank you.

#Icon with default class

```
 <mat-icon class="card-icon">group</mat-icon>
```

#Condition

```
<mat-icon class="active-icon" [class.newclass]="currentTabElement === 'group'">group</mat-icon>
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass

Comment: I think No Sir ,.

Comment: I mean it's basically the same thing. With that information in mind you can build your own solution. And welcome to StackOverflow, anyway!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: conditional class with \*ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `ng class` property in angular to switch between CSS classes as an example, if I want to create a toggle button that needs to switch between the dark background and light background I can do the following changes.

**HTML file**
`<div [ngClass]="{'black-background':blacked, 'white-background':!blacked}">`

**CSS / SCSS file**

```
.black-background {
    background-color: #000;
}
.white-background {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

**TypeScript file**
In the typescript file, you need to have the property `blacked` value which we pass in the HTML tag need to be `true` or `false`

```
blacked = true;
```

for now, the `blacked` value is true, so `black-background` value is `true` so now we can see the black background. If property `blacked=false;` then the `white-background` value is `true` because we pass `white-background:!blacked`. So like that we can toggle between the CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

```js
 <mat-icon [ngClass]="{'card-icon': true, 'active-icon': currentTabElement === 'group'}">group</mat-icon>
```

The code above will add the `card-icon` class to **all** icons, and the `active-icon` class **only** when the condition `currentTabElement === 'group'` evaluates to true.

Comment: I tried the above implementation Sir  , but it does not work
[ngClass]="{'card-icon': true, 'active-icon': currentTabElement === 'group'}"

Comment: @TimLaunders there was a missing closing bracket, I've edited the code. I was able to run this locally, are you sure the condition is correct ? Do you see the `active-icon` class being added when the condition evaluates to `true` ?