# ngClass is there a better way to have a style always present and add other based on condition

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm very new to ng-class and I need to have a default class always applied to a span and add another class when a certain condition happens

```html
<span
    [ngClass]="{'timeString': true, 'disabledText': conditionalExpression}">
</span>
```

My css contains:

```css
.timeString{
    width: 50px;
}

.disabledText {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}
```

I have checked similar questions but not found what I'm looking for.

Basically I want to get rid of the `'timeString': true` part

Comment: <span class="timeString" [ngClass]="{'disabledText': conditionalExpression}"></span>

Comment: feel free to post answer so I can give you credit for your help, thanks

Comment: Isn't this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68520866/16497617

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa which also seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass, but the title and wording did not match to my way of searching - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
<span class="timeString" [ngClass]="{'disabledText': conditionalExpression}"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to pass an array of classes

```js
// you would add more classes when needed somewhere in your component
// based on your logic

public myClassList = ['timeString'];

<span [ngClass]="myClassList"> </span>
```

Comment: the listClass is dynamic, so I would have to keep it updated in a property or similar ? so for more complex scenarios this could be useful

Comment: Yes, that would be a property in your component and you can add or remove so multiple classes without adjusting the template.

Comment: the issue in my case is that the expresion to evaluate is quite complex, it depends on many variables, and keeping a propery updated, each time any variable is updated is quite complex at this time. So having the condition on the template is better at this time Thanks

Comment: It's the same with the condition in template. It will be evaluated all the time when angular change detection runs. As for my example you can also use a function ```getClassList()``` where you put your conditional logic and return the array. But if you have just one dynamic class the accepted answer is just fine.

Comment: I'm not talking about when it gets evaluated, I'm talking that current code depends on a lot of boolean flags that are set in MANY methods and keeping the list of classes of updated will be a lot of unwanted work. Also never call methods from an Angular Template - https://betterprogramming.pub/why-you-should-never-use-methods-inside-templates-in-angular-497e0e11f948