# How to change color text when using ngClass inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, ng-class

I want to change color of text when using `ngClass`.

I have the JSON like below but I have a lot of data:

items: [
{
itemId: "22222",
category: 'A',
total: 100
},
{
itemId: "666666",
category: 'A',
total: 80
},
{
itemId: "555",
category: 'B',
total: 50
}
]

I create on `.scss`

```
   &.is-green {
      color: green;
    }
    &.is-red {
      color: red;
    }
```

I want to use it something like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items;> 
    <div>{{item.category}}</div>
    <div 
      [ngClass]="{
        'is-green': item.total ,
        'is-red':item.total
         }"
       >
       {{item.total}}</div>
    </div>
```

From this data I want to display total with min value exp `total: 50` color green and total with max value exp `total: 100` color red

Answer (score 0):

Access directly to the class attributes:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items;> 
    <div>{{item.category}}</div>
    <div [class.is-green]="item.total <= 50" [class.is-red]="item.total > 50" >
        {{item.total}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, yes  sure but I have a lot of items with difference totale. I

Comment: Edited for your need, that's work with any items you want

Comment: Yes but I don't now which are the total number. Maybe total should be 10 or with minus.

Comment: I edit my question. If you can please help me. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of how to conditionally add classes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974490/6478359

I have prepared a sample project for your problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cjpr4v

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div>{{ item.category }}</div>
  <div
    [ngClass]="{
      'is-green': item.total === 50,
      'is-yellow': item.total === 80,
      'is-red': item.total === 100
    }"
  >
    {{ item.total }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I have a lot of data, and from those data I want to color only min total and max total. I don't know which are totals number. I want something dynamic

Comment: Actually, your question has been answered by me and @Xavier Brassoud below. Maybe you want something different. It would be helpful if you could explain your question more clearly.

Comment: Yes you are right. Maybe should be get min and max of total

Comment: I edit my question. If you can please help me. Thnaks