# How to expand parent block height when ng if display

Tags: css, angularjs

i need to change height of the parent element when ng-If is true and it display a rectangle, but have no idea how.

My structure looks like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <form> 
        <div ng-if="sth" class="child"> 
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

when the if statement is true, then parent height has to change.

Comment: You may find the answer to this similar question helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague... not sure what height you want to set etc... but here's an example:

```
<div class="parent" ng-style="{ height: sth ? '400px' : 'auto' }">
    <form> 
        <div ng-if="sth" class="child"> 
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```