# Type 'boolean' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: angular

Upgrading angular 11 to angular 13 getting issue like Type 'boolean' cannot be used as an index type can i know what need to change in below code.

```
[ngClass]="{true: 'through'}[employee.status]"
```

Comment: Error is in this section "{true: 'through'}", true is a boolean keyword in angular

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe this helps:
`[class. through]="employee.status"`

Comment: No error is showing in [employee.status] here.

Comment: Hi @Zerotwelve I tried but it's not worked.

Comment: please describe what your goal is and what `employee.status` is/can be

Comment: issue fixed after changed like this [ngClass]="{'through' :employee.status }" thank you

Comment: add your solution in the answer section and close/resolve the issue ;)
maybe someone in future will have the same question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Type 'boolean' cannot be used as an index type issue is fixed by changing the
`[ngClass]="{'through' :employee.status }"` by referring to [Angular: conditional class with *ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass)