# Parser Error: Conditional expression requires all 3 expressions

Tags: angular13

I'm new in web development.

I want to have 3 conditions here and I don't know how to do it:

```
<span class="badge"[ngClass]="[row.etat ? ' badge-info' : ' badge-success' || ' badge-danger']">
{{ row.etat ? ' PLANIFIER ' : 'EN_COURS' || 'REALISER' }}</span>
```

Comment: Does [Angular: conditional class with *ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass) help?

Comment: Yeah thank you so much @AndrewMorton, I used the multiple option and it worked for me