# How to use class binding with font-awesome icon?

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to display two different icons based on the value of a variable. I want to show up arrow if it's true or down arrow if it's false. But it seems like it's not working at all and I can't figure out why. Here's the code-

```
<div class="custom-class" (click)="changeValue()">
<i class="fa fa-lg " [ngClass]="isValue ? 'fa-chevron-circle-up' : 'fa-chevron-circle-down'"></i>
</div>
```

My component class has something like this-

```
private isValue: boolean = true;
changeValue() {
    this.isValue = !this.isValue;
  }
```

I don't know why it doesn't work properly. I'm using font-awesome v6 and angular 14. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What does "doesn't work properly" mean? Are the classes being applied to the document?

Comment: You might need the `fa-solid` companion class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: conditional class with \*ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass)

Comment: @isherwood no the classes are not being applied to the component after the click.
Yeah I tried using fa-solid as well but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to angular-fontawesome and it seems to be working with that.
ngClass does not work with @fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.9.0 correctly because the `<i>` dom is replaced with an `<svg>` dom.
[Here's the link to the github issue.](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/15333)

Comment: Thanks. You should include the relevant information from the issue here in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Think you're using `[ngClass]` a bit wrong. Here are the different ways you can do exactly that:

Using `[ngClass]`:

```
<i class="fa fa-lg "
   [ngClass]="{ 'fa-chevron-circle-up': isValue, 'fa-chevron-circle-down': !isValue }"
></i>
```

Using `[class.*]` binding (my favorite):

```
<i class="fa fa-lg "
   [class.fa-chevron-circle-up]="isValue"
   [class.fa-chevron-circle-down]="!isValue"
></i>
```

More docs on class binding can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/class-binding

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried these but it's still not changing the classes. Can it be due to new fontawesome version update? Cause I moved from 4 to 6 and earlier the same code was working.

Comment: Guess you have two problems then! The classes have changed names since then: https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle-chevron-up?s=regular. The new name for that one is `fa-circle-chevron-up`. If that doesn't fix it, look at the page and inspect element. Check if that element has the classes. If it does have the classes but nothing shows up, it's a CSS issue. If it does not have the classes at all, it's an Angular issue.