# how to do [ngclass] for two different CSS.if vaule is empty and it is a value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

how did I use the ng-class for this
I want to create an auto-complete dropdown like this image.[image: search bar with auto-complete dropdown].
if there is a value I need this.  [image: search bar with autocomplete dropdown]
if there is no value I need like this a normal search bar like this[!search bar without auto-complete dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agrgz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agrgz.png)

HTML, CSS, angular

```
HTML

<div fxLayout="row" class="search">
        <div fxFlex="80">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="search-box">
            <input class="search-input" matInput placeholder="Search Vendors" [formControl]="myControl"
              [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="searchKey" />
            <mat-icon matPrefix class="search-icon">
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span></mat-icon>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="cancel-icon" aria-label="Clear"  (click)="onSearchClear()">
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined">close</span></mat-icon>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="fliter-icon" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #trigger="matMenuTrigger">
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined">filter_alt</span></mat-icon>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="menu-form-wrapper" [hasBackdrop]="false">
              <app-vendor-filter></app-vendor-filter>
            </mat-menu>
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
                {{option.supplierName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.search-icon {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.fliter-icon {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cancel-icon{
  font-size: 22px;

}


.search-input {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}


.search-box {
  font-size: 12px;
  
}

:host::ng-deep
  .mat-form-field-appearance-outline
  .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 58px 0 0 58px !important;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

:host::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 0 58px 58px 0 !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  background-color: #eaecef;
  border-radius: 58px;
}

:host::ng-deep .search-box .mat-form-field-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
:host::ng-deep .search-box .mat-input-underline.mat-form-field-underline {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

I am expecting like this.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: conditional class with \*ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass)